# How Do I Set PHP to Download database to D drive?

Tags: php

i have a files for download mysql database using php.which is working properly.but i want to download codes to specific folder created in D drive

```
 $backup_file_name = $database_name . '_backup_' . time() . '.sql';
    $fileHandler = fopen($backup_file_name, 'w+');
    $number_of_lines = fwrite($fileHandler, $sqlScript);
    fclose($fileHandler); 

    // Download the SQL backup file to the browser
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($backup_file_name));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($backup_file_name));
    file_put_contents('D:\dbbackups', $backup_file_name);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($backup_file_name);
    exec('rm ' . $backup_file_name);
```

but file id download inside the project folder.any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: The server has no control over where the browser puts the file. You can set a default download folder in the browser.

Comment: You can't access local folder of your pc

Comment: you might want to have a look at the [File API](https://web.dev/file-system-access/)

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen that's for Javascript, not PHP, and only supports 2 browsers currently. It's practically experimental, and may or may not be relevant to this scenario (unless perhaps the OP writes some JS to make a fetch() request to the PHP, and then tries to save the file) - we have no indication whether a browser app is the client here or not.

Answer (score 2):

From PHP, you can't.

Your server-side PHP application has no knowledge of, or control over, the application or device which is making the HTTP request. All it does it return some data and headers to the requesting client.

Your server / PHP has no idea whether

- the client device even has a D: drive (or even runs an O/S which uses drive letters), or whether a specific folder exists within it
- the client will even treat the response as a file and try to save it somewhere

And even if it did know the above, then

- your server would have no permissions to access the client-side device or its storage media.

If what you're suggesting was possible it would be a big security / privacy problem. But it would still be impractical even then, because of my first point.

---

What you *can* do to help yourself in this situation though is to write your own client-side program which makes the HTTP request to your server to execute the PHP, receives the data in the response and saves it to the location you want. Or if you're doing this via a browser you can set the browser's default download location to that folder.